# Undercabinet lighting wiring

Tags: electrical, lighting, low-voltage

I have a new build project where my kitchen was wired for undercabinet lighting.  I would like to attach 2 sections of LED strip lights to the upper cabinets, but am unsure of how to wire the part labeled "B" in the attached diagram.

My current plan is to attach an LED driver to "A" then attach the LED lights to the driver.
I would also cut the wire at "B" resulting in 4 wires (possibly 6 if there's a ground) and attaching them to another LED driver using wire nuts securing the groupings of 3 wires (+, -, neutral).

Are there any issues with this approach?  Do I need 2 separate drivers at each section?

There are currently junction boxes mounted to the cabinets that house the wires.  Should I put the driver inside the junction box, or just the joined wires?

Thank you!

[image]

Later drawing from comments:-

[image]

Comment: My preference is to only use mains voltage to power a low voltage LED driver.  You say you have 120V, so you must be in North America, yes?  What's in the gap between cabinets?

Answer (score 4):

Does your wall switch have a full set of live, neutral, earth? Are your LED low voltage, after the driver?

If the answer to both of those is 'yes' then you can put the driver anywhere between the switch & the first LED. From there, use the existing wiring [so long as it goes nowhere else except what's shown in the diagram] to each bank of LEDs.  They wire in parallel, so as long as your driver can drive the total load [it ought to, LEDs don't eat much] & *mark it as low voltage everywhere you can reach it*, then you're good to go.
You don't need to run the earth through for low voltage, so long as your driver is earthed [if it is designed for it], if there are earth wires on the LV side, you can just clip them back.

[image]

My own kitchen is very similar - I run the LEDs directly from the existing cooker hood, just added the necessary driver above it. It all switches from the hood light switch. I also removed the mains lighting from the hood itself, and put LED strip in there too.

If your mains supply actually comes in from A rather than at the switch side, then you could mirror the above setup - but then your switch would only disengage the LED lamps, not the driver, which would remain on all the time. You might need to check whether that would upset it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I actually went back to take a closer look at what was within the junction boxes, and it looks like the electricians cut the wire already, so placing the driver at the location you indicated is no longer feasible. :(  Here's an updated image: https://imgur.com/a/afT42hG.  The Romex wires have a full set of wires (+, -, neutral) and I plan to purchase 24V LED strips--any recommendations on the driver/strips would be appreciated as well!!

Comment: There's no electrical difference between the first & second images. Sorry, but we don't do actual product recommendations on here.